# Need help determining why my voltage level drops

Tags: voltage, power, integrated-circuit

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Hi everyone.  I'm having troubles with this circuit.  I need the 7404 VCC pin to be at about 5V.  With the 7404 chip in the circuit physically the voltage at that pin is about 1.36V.  When I remove the chip it goes back up to 5V.  I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that resistive divider, R2 and R4. Calculate the Thevenin equivalent. Now use the 7404 data sheet to see how much current a 7404 draws, and calculate the voltage drop across the equivalent resistance. You'll see that the current needed loads down the divider output.

Instead of using a divider, use a regulator such as a 7805.

Comment: An easier solution would be to make an inverter out of another 2N7000 and 10k ohm.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simpler solution, just make an inverter with an N-type transistor and a resistor. It would probably me more interesting to know *what* the circuit is for, because this circuit looks *strange*.

[image: Inverter from another transistor]

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0AR%20784%20256%20784%20208%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0Af%20736%20448%20784%20448%200%201.5%200.02%0Ar%20784%20336%20784%20256%200%201000%0Az%20880%20464%20880%20336%201%200.805904783%205.6%0Aw%20880%20336%20976%20336%202%0Ar%20976%20336%20976%20400%200%2010000%0Ar%20976%20400%20976%20464%200%2014000%0Aw%20784%20336%20880%20336%201%0Ag%20784%20464%20784%20480%200%0Ag%20880%20464%20880%20480%200%0Ag%20976%20464%20976%20480%200%0Aw%20784%20336%20784%20432%201%0Af%20640%20448%20688%20448%200%201.5%200.02%0Ag%20688%20464%20688%20480%200%0Aw%20688%20432%20736%20432%200%0Aw%20736%20432%20736%20448%200%0Ar%20688%20432%20688%20256%200%2010000%0Aw%20688%20256%20784%20256%200%0AL%20640%20448%20608%20448%200%201%20false%205%200%0Aw%20976%20400%201024%20400%200%0Aw%201024%20400%201056%20400%202%0Ax%20653%20512%20715%20515%204%2016%202N7000%0Ax%20751%20512%20813%20515%204%2016%202N7000%0A) if you want to play around.